# Error while starting react-native application

Tags: javascript, linux, react-native, ubuntu-16.04

I am not able to run react-native on `port 8088`. Sometimes it runs and sometimes it doesn't. Last time I restarted the laptop so it ran and now again it isn't running. Is there any permanent solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The command should be:

```
react-native start --port 8088
```

You can use this command to check the options:

```
react-native start --help
```